# How to modify a cube (tabular) in SSAS / Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, cube, tabular, power-bi-report-server

I'm a beginner in SSAS. 
The person who created the project is gone so I don't have any contact to help me.

**We have:**

SQL Server Management Studio
Visual Studio (2017)
Power BI RS

---

Someone created 3 cubes (tabular). I need to open them because in order to **understand the model, modify one measure, add a dimension**.

But I do not achieve to open one!

I find a file "visual_studio" on which there are 1 .bim file and 1 .smproj
I can't read them with VisualStudio. 
Is this the right file location?

I don't know how to open a cube and to have access to its information.
On the internet, it's always "open with ssas" but what's ssas exactly? Do we speak about the visual studio or SQL server?

I'm lost and sorry, I can't find a simple tutorial on the Internet. 
I'm starting from scratch, thanks by advance for your help,

Have a nice day,

Comment: do you have a .sln file in the folder? Do you have SSDT installed? BTW a cube is not tabular, they are not the same.

Comment: @StelioK thanks for ur answer. I'm working on Tabular CUBE and I don't have any .sln file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out .sln file which is a solution file to open your model in SSAS using Visual Studio.

Make sure you installed SQL Server Data Tools in your Visual Studio.

[You can download from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15)